# Reset class attributes for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python class like this one:

```
class MyClass():
    class_att = 0

@classmethod
def increase_value(cls):
    att = att + 1
```

I want to prepare two tests for the class: in one of them it checks the initial value and in another one that it is increased with the method.

```
test_initial_value(self):
    self.assertEqual(MyClass.class_att, 0)

test_increase_value(self):
     MyClass.increase_value()
     self.assertEqual(MyClass.class_att, 1)
```

But there is a dependence between both tests, since first one will only pass if it is run before the second. So I would need to "reset" the class attributes. Is this possible? How could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

It is good that you try to keep your tests independent.  In your particular case, you have several options.

Option 1: You can provide an explicit static init method to your class `MyClass`.  Such a method can then be used in your tests.

```
test_increase_value(self):
    MyClass.init()
    MyClass.increase_value()
    self.assertEqual(MyClass.class_att, 1)
```

This makes it unnecessary for your unit-tests to directly access the class's internals to bring back the class into is original state.  It may also be a good choice in case you find other reasons in your code to have such a possibility, not only for unit-testing reasons.

Option 2: Reset the class's state from your unit-tests, as was shown by Mebin Joe.  This makes your tests slightly less stable, because you are somehow duplicating the class's internals and thus have to change your tests is the class changes.  You can do it with `setUp` and `teardown` (which in this case would be preferrable), or directly from within each test (just for demonstration):

```
test_increase_value(self):
    MyClass.class_att = 0
    MyClass.increase_value()
    self.assertEqual(MyClass.class_att, class_att_before + 1)
    MyClass.class_att = 0 # bring back to initial state
```

Option 3: Write your tests such they also work reliably independent of the class's state:

```
test_increase_value(self):
    class_att_before = MyClass.class_att
    MyClass.increase_value()
    self.assertEqual(MyClass.class_att, class_att_before + 1)
```

This has a couple of disadvantages: The test code becomes harder to read, and it may not be easy to implement all desired test cases this way.

Summary: I would recommend to choose option 1, unless you really don't want such an init method.  Then, option 2 is preferrable over 3, for which I do not see many uses.

Answer (score -1):

Reset variables to None, the total memory is cleared after every unittest.

Sample:

```
class TestEx(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.class_att = "value"

    def teardown(self):
        self.class_att = None
```

Comment: But class_att is an attribute of the class MyClass, not from the TestEx class. How could it work?

Comment: TestEx is just an example class for demonstration. Please feel free to refactor.